# Session without authentication with MemoryCacheClient in servicestack with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, servicestack

i am new to Servicestack. I am having  MVC4 application and servicestack application **deployed on diffrent servers** .
I want to use the servicestack session without authentication with MemoryCacheClient.

i am not able to understand the explanation given in

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions

I want to check if session is there for each request and if seesion is null create new session with custom value as user id.

My configure method is as followes

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            
      
            // in global request filter check if session exists
            this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
            {  
                //check if session exists 
                var sessionId = req.GetSessionId();
                if (sessionId == null)
                {
                    //if no populate session with user defined data ( user id from requestDto)
                }
                else
                { 
                   //how to get the values from session ?
                }
    }
```

Please help .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SessionFeature` already registers their own Global Request Filter to automatically create missing Temporary or Permanent Session Ids (i.e. `ss-id` or `ss-pid`).

It sounds like you want to register a [Custom AuthEvent](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#auth-events) to respond to different events in the session lifecycle, i.e. `IAuthEvents.OnCreated()`.

Comment: thanks. one more question  how to authenticate nework service credentials in servicestack

Comment: @amol register `AspNetWindowsAuthProvider` in AuthFeature on Server and ServiceClients can use `client. Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`

Comment: i have added  Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
            new AspNetWindowsAuthProvider(this) { AllowAllWindowsAuthUsers = true }, 
            }
            ));  in apphost  and  at client  i am using var client = new JsonServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationUrl"])
            {
                Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            };

Comment: to use network credentials ,can i use  var client = new JsonServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationUrl"])
            {            //network authentication
                Credentials  = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain)                
            }; and use custom authontication at servicestack ?

Comment: @amol Sure it's just passed down to the underlying `HttpWebRequest` making the HTTP Request, so it supports anything it supports.